# Dynamic access to MySQL database in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am looking for some way how to access MySQL database more dynamically.

For example, I want to insert some text to my table.
I have some method called `insert()` which is called approximately every half of the second and does the insert stuff.

The code looks like this:

```
public void insert(String string) {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(...);
        java.sql.Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
        stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO mytable (mytext) VALUES ('"+ string +"')");
        conn.close();
}
```

But I really think this could cause many problems because it is opening and closing connections too often.

So isn't there any way to open some "MySQLStream" to the database and print the data to it without opening and closing the connection again and again?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: You should be closing connection that is a good practice, the answer here is to use ConnectionPool.

Comment: Use "Connection pools", if you are worried about open/close connections frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Connection object at the beginning of the program, and use it for every query. Close it only at the end of the program.

Oftentimes one Connection is good, so you may declare it as static.

```
public static java.sql.Connection conn;
public static void buildConnection()
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(...);
}

public void insert(String string) 
{
    java.sql.Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
    stat.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO mytable (mytext) VALUES ('"+ string +"')");
}
```

In the program, you may do the following:

```
buildConnection();
...
insert("....");
insert("....");
...
conn.close();
```

Comment: Yes thats also the option I was thinking about. And I am going to use it if I won't find other solution.